# Struct Not Used

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I have an app with 50+ questions. Each question has:

1. A question,
2. Correct answer
3. Three incorrect answers
4. An image name

So I made a struct with those properties. Only one question will be on screen at a time so I started settings up my questions like this:

```
let question1 = structName... (pass question info)
let question2 = structName... (pass question 2 info)
```

However, this is getting a "variable unused" warning. What am I doing wrong and how do I do it right??

Comment: 1) This is a really horrible design choice. You need to keep dozens of variables around that all point to the same kind of things. You need to repeat everything over and over again. That's what arrays are for, for example. 2) That warning means you are not using one of your variables at all. Probably means, one of your questions is *never* used. 3) Post real code and real error messages - as it stands, we can only guess.

Comment: almost always when you are enumerating variables with 1, 2, 3 you are doing something very wrong. Use an array and indices.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to combine the wrongAnswers into an array but I was able to use this design pattern by storing all the structs in an array, which made sure they were all used:

```
    //Question one
    let questionPackage = QuestionInfo(
        questionNum: 1,
        questionType: "Single",
        answer: "Correct answer here",
        wrongAnswer_1: "This is wrong",
        wrongAnswer_2: "So is this",
        wrongAnswer_3: "So is not right"
    )

    //Question two
    let questionPackage2 = QuestionInfo(
        questionNum: 1,
        questionType: "Single",
        answer: "Correct answer here",
        wrongAnswer_1: "This is wrong",
        wrongAnswer_2: "So is this",
        wrongAnswer_3: "So is not right"
    )

    let questionArray = [questionPackage,questionPackage2]
    let loadQuestion = questionArray[questionNum]
```