# How do I organize this data?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have an iOS app with 50+ questions. Each question has:

1. A question
2. Correct answer
3. Three incorrect answers
4. An image name

Originally I tried using a struct (like below) and creating a constant for each question that I could call/load when the user gets that question:

```
struct QuestionInfo {
    var question: String
    var correctAnswer: String
    var wrongAnswer_1: String?
    var wrongAnswer_2: String?
    var wrongAnswer_3: String?
    var imageName: String
}
```

However, I've been told that was a dumb idea and that I should use arrays. I understand arrays are meant for this type of thing, but how do I keep it organized?

It seems like I'll have six arrays:

```
let question = ["Is Mars a planet?", "Is Spain in Africa?", "+50 more"]
let correctAnswer = ["Yes", "No", "+50 more"]
//+Four more arrays
```

Each array will be 50+ items long and each question will be in six different lists at once, making it difficult for me to stay organized. Should I create an array/struct for each question and then make an array of arrays/structs??

```
let questionPackage = QuestionInfo(
        question: "Is Mars a planet?",
        correctAnswer: "Yes",
        wrongAnswer_1: "No",
        wrongAnswer_2: "No one knows.",
        wrongAnswer_3: "It's a candy bar."
        imageName: "MarsPhoto",
    )
let questionPackage2  = QuestionInfo(
        question: "Is Spain in Africa?",
        correctAnswer: "No",
        wrongAnswer_1: "Yes",
        wrongAnswer_2: "It's up for debate",
        wrongAnswer_3: "Duh, it's in South America."
        imageName: "SpanishFlag",
    )

//Array of structs
let array = [questionPackage, questionPackage2, etc]
```

I'm trying to choose based on what will run most efficiently and a normal design pattern.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the comment on your original question; an array of structs as in your last block of code was what was meant.  You can also create a plist file to store your questions and load that into an array at runtime rather than having to have all of that creation code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I don't see any problem with a struct like yours. Maybe just slightly improved

```
struct Question {
    let question: String
    let correctAnswer: String
    let wrongAnswers: (String, String, String)
    let imageName: String
}
```

### Usage

```
let question = Question(
    question: "First captain of the Enterprise?",
    correctAnswer: "Pike",
    wrongAnswers: ("Kirk", "Picard", "Archer"),
    imageName: "Enterprise"
)

print(question.question)
print(question.correctAnswer)
print(question.wrongAnswers.0)
print(question.wrongAnswers.1)
print(question.wrongAnswers.2)
```

Comment: Well that's great news because the struct sounded good to me. However I posted (link at end of comment) and was criticized for creating so many variables/constants. "This is a really horrible design choice. You need to keep dozens of variables around that all point to the same kind of things."  But your view is that its an okay design and wouldn't cause efficiency problems? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285406/struct-not-used

Comment: @DaveG: Ok I understand the comment about avoiding several variables named with indexes like `wrongAnswer0`, `wrongAnswer1`, `wrongAnswer2`. Just use the code I posted into my question. It will do the job.

Comment: I would suggest perhaps an array of answers an an int that denotes the index of the correct answer.

Comment: @Paulw11: The problem I see with arrays is that you cannot be sure at compile that it does contains exactly the expected number of elements. I could contains more values or even be empty. By this point of view I think a tuple is more secure.

Comment: You shouldn't need to know at compile time how many elements the array contains.  You handle this at run time, then you can have a question with 4 possible answers, 2 possible answers etc.  It also makes it much simpler to load the question object from some form of persistent store such as a plist or from a server.

Comment: When I try to combine the wrongAnswers into an array, it messes up my struct init "wrongAnswers: Array<String?>)" <-- Gets an error saying it can't assign that type to a type of (String?, String, String?) -- So then I changed my init to --> wrongAnswers: Array<String?, String?, String?>) <-- That says something like "expecting one" but "receiving three". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of structs like below

Struct

```
struct Question {
var q: String
var a: String
var wa: (String, String, String)
}
```

Array

```
let array = [Question(q: "q", a: "a", wa: ("wa", "wa", "wa")), Question(q: "q", a: "a", wa: ("wa", "wa", "wa"))]
```

Usage

```
print(array[0].q)
print(array[0].a)
print(array[0].wa)
```